# Error: No such file or directory on Xcode

Tags: c, xcode

I'm new on Xcode and trying to write c code on it. But, I get error like

`Error: No such file or directory Program ended with exit code: 255`

Variables.txt has already been in same folder. But, I don't know why I get the error.

```
FILE *inp;
inp = fopen("Variables.txt","r");
if(inp == NULL)
{ perror("Error"); return -1; }
```

Comment: The Variables.txt must be placed in the same directory of your executable. I find it better to change on Project Settings the location of the compiled outputs to Working Directory and the Derived Data relative to Working Directory as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I've already said I'm new on Xcode. I get solution. Be sure a file which will be related to the code should be in the exec folder.
[image: solution]